# Lua gmatch store captured groups as an array

Tags: arrays, string, lua, lua-patterns

I'm rather new to Lua. For each match of `gmatch`, I would like to put the capture group results into an array.

The idea is so I get all the capture groups for each match, as an array, so I can do operations on this array, e.g. convert each capture group to an int.

How would I change the following, so it prints `3` `2` `1`?

```lua
function split_ipv4(str)
    for parts in str:gmatch('(%d%d?%d?)%.(%d%d?%d?)%.(%d%d?%d?)%.(%d%d?%d?), ') do
       print(parts[4])
    end
end

split_ipv4('192.168.0.3, 192.168.0.2, 192.168.0.1')
```

Changing `parts` to `p1, p2, p3, p4` and printing `p4` works, but is there a way of not creating a variable for each group?

Answer (score 3):

The most simple way is to change `parts` to `p1, p2, p3, p4`
But in case of variable-phobia:

```
function split_ipv4(str)
   for addr in str:gmatch'%d%d?%d?%.%d%d?%d?%.%d%d?%d?%.%d%d?%d?' do
      local parts = {addr:match'(%d+)%.(%d+)%.(%d+)%.(%d+)'}
      print(parts[4])
    end
end

split_ipv4('192.168.0.3, 192.168.0.2, 192.168.0.1')
```

Comment: +1. Thanks for the answer. I  thought of this idea too, but ig like you said it's not much more better than `p1, p2, p3, p4` for IPv4. It's better in the case of IPv6 I suppose.

Comment: IPv6 is not covered by a single Lua pattern.